# How to stop the scroll of tableview after reload data?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have tried some of the methods provided by others but its doesn't work.

```
CGPoint offset = tableView.contentOffset;
[tableView.messageTable reloadData];
[tableView setContentOffset:offset];
```

I an unable to get the index path at this moment.How can I prevent the tableview from scrolling?

Comment: What do you want to do?  It's not clear.

Comment: You want it to be after reloadData? you can use this method `scrollViewWillEndDragging:` when user stopped dragging.

Comment: As I understand your question you want to stop scrolling when you call `reloadData` am I right?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop the scroll of tableview set this

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

After sometimes you want to start the scroll of tableview set like this

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Hope this will help you.